# UITableViewCell displays incorrect string

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a disconcerting issue in that I have a `UITableViewCell` that does not update the displayed value of its underlying data.  To the code:

```
class ReviewInspectionViewController: UIViewController {
    private lazy var locationsDataSource: ReviewInspectionDataSource = ReviewInspectionDataSource(tableView: tableView, delegate: self)

   override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
       .. retrieve data from Realm
       .. process data and place in data object defined as var data : [Any] = []

       locationsDataSource.data.append((location.title,data))
   }
}
class ReviewInspectionDataSource: NSObject, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let location = data[indexPath.section]
        let item = location.content[indexPath.row]

        if let item = item as? String {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(for: indexPath, cellType: ReviewChecklistItemCell.self)

            cell.descriptionLabel.text = item

            return cell
        }
        ....
    }
}
```

Works fine the first time and the correct string is shown on the screen.  I tab to a different view (the underlying `UIViewController` is in a `UITabViewController`), make a change and then tab back, I can confirm that the changed data is being set correctly in this line:

```
cell.descriptionLabel.text = item
```

I can even print out the value of `cell.description.text` by adding a line like this:

```
cell.descriptionLabel.text = item
print("Cell value", cell.descriptionLabel.text)
```

and it prints out the changed value BUT the screen shows the **old** value. The `UITableViewCell` itself is extremely simple:

```
class ReviewChecklistItemCell: UITableViewCell, NibReusable {
    @IBOutlet weak var descriptionLabel: UILabel!
}
```

The datasource class is loaded from the `UIViewController.viewWillAppear` method holding onto the `UITableView`. I have never seen this happen before, thoughts on what the issue is?

Comment: Can you provide more code/context? Where you you updating the label? In `cellForRowAt`?  Where/how are you telling the tableview to reload the cell?

Comment: Paulw11 hit it on the head. You need to make sure you are calling tableView.reloadData() in viewWillAppear or somewhere similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are updating the cell description label instead of updating the actual source of the data.

So instead of

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(for: indexPath, cellType: ReviewChecklistItemCell.self)
cell.descriptionLabel.text = item
```

I would update your data source at that indexPath

```
dataSource[indexPath.row] = item
tableView.reloadData()
```

Comment: I am not updating data, I am presenting data in a UILabel embedded within a UITableViewCell.

Comment: What function are you changing the data for the UILabel in? @PerryHoekstra

Comment: The class is a datasource class defined as: class ReviewInspectionDataSource: NSObject, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate. This datasource class is populated in the viewWillAppear of the UIViewController.

Comment: Can you show that class and the viewWillAppear please? @PerryHoekstra

Comment: Try calling tableView.reloadData() in viewWillAppear @PerryHoekstra